# show images for taxonomy terms in referenced node

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

D7 question. I need to have a "clients" taxonomy with an image extra field on each term (the client's logo). Then I have a "project" content type. Projects belong to specific clients, ie the project content type has a term reference field to the client taxonomy.

When I click on a "project", I want to see the clients logo and not (only) the term name. This seems possible by following these instructions http://drupal.org/node/1224916, but this article is misleading: it suggests having an entity-reference field on the project content type instead of a term-reference. The problem with that approach is that when you connect a term and content by an entitity field, these two are not connected as far as taxonomy is concerned. So you lose all taxonomy functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive you can achieve this with the normal "Term reference" field, and a custom template file: `field--field_my_custom_field.tpl.php` in your theme folder which renders the image. You can access the value of your custom field through `$items[$key]['#options']['entity']->field_my_custom_field` where `$key` is the array index (if you have more than 1 value for this field, first item is index `0`, second is `1` etc, usually you should just loop through the $items like `foreach($items as $item)` and then you can do `$item['#options']['entity']->field_my_custom_field`)

You may need to have a `field.tpl.php` (copy from *root*/modules/field/theme then duplicate it and rename the duplicate into `field--field_my_custom_field.tpl.php`) in your theme folder in order for it to work (or templates folder inside your theme folder, basically same folder as your custom `field--field_my_custom_field.tpl.php`) (*Not 100% sure, but this was the case in Drupal 6*)

API documentation for [field.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7)

This may also come in handy: [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7)

Sorry for unsure answer with a lot of unknowns, just trying to help :)